# Why is $.get() requesting different url on click than specified?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to refresh a list on click based on some variables. First fetch which happens when document loads happens perfectly but the subsequent request is failing becuase ajax get is requesting incorrect url.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function fetch() {
        var defaults = {
            'date': app.fetch.date,
            'company': app.fetch.company
        };
        $.get("https://example.com/dispatch/manifested/all", defaults, function(response) {
            app.manifested = response['data'];
        });
    };

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        fetch(); // works as intended

        $('#get-list').click(function() {
            fetch(); // fails
        });
    });

</script>
```

The initial command fetches the specified url but the next on tries to get '`/manifested/all`' instead of '`/dispatch/manifested/all`'.

I have tried relative url and absolute url, sending it is post and get.

Comment: i think, the 2nd time your url is domain.com/module/ so it automatically use the controller/action only.  did you try without domain,  /dispatch/manifested/all. what your network says 404?

Comment: Yes I tried it without the domain as well. 404 because it tries to skip one level.